# Best approach for specific Object/Image Recognition task?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, computer-vision, pattern-recognition, image-recognition

I'm searching for an certain object in my photograph:

Object:  Outline of a rectangle with an X in the middle.  It looks like a rectangular checkbox.  That's all.  So, no fill, just lines.  The rectangle will have the same ratios of length to width but it could be any size or any rotation in the photograph.

I've looked a whole bunch of image recognition approaches.  But I'm trying to determine the best for this specific task.  Most importantly, the object is made of lines and is not a filled shape.  Also, there is no perspective distortion, so the rectangular object will always have right angles in the photograph.

Any ideas?  I'm hoping for something that I can implement fairly easily.

Thanks all.

Comment: The plane of the X will always be parallel to the plane of the image I assume? So no perspective distortion of the X?

Comment: Updated question, see above. (no distortion at all, the viewpoint will be perfectly orthogonal to the object, i hope that terminology is correct, but I think you know what I mean).

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a corner detector (e.g. Harris) to find the corners of the box, the ends and the intersection of the X. That simplifies the problem to finding points in the right configuration.

Edit (response to comment):

I'm assuming you can find the corner points in your image, the 4 corners of the rectangle, the 4 line endings of the X and the center of the X, plus a few other corners in the image due to noise or objects in the background. That simplifies the problem to finding a set of 9 points in the right configuration, out of a given set of points.

My first try would be to look at each corner point A. Then I'd iterate over the points B close to A. Now if I assume that (e.g.) A is the upper left corner of the rectangle and B is the lower right corner, I can easily calculate, where I would expect the other corner points to be in the image. I'd use some nearest-neighbor search (or a library like FLANN) to see if there are corners where I'd expect them. If I can find a set of points that matches these expected positions, I know where the symbol would be, if it is present in the image.

You have to try if that is good enough for your application. If you have too many false positives (sets of corners of other objects that accidentially form a rectangle + X), you could check if there are lines (i.e. high contrast in the right direction) where you would expect them. And you could check if there is low contrast where there are no lines in the pattern. This should be relatively straightforward once you know the points in the image that correspond to the corners/line endings in the object you're looking for.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how to perform the "search" after doing a corner or edge detection.  Because I have implemented both and can see that it definitely picks up object features.  But what is my next step in being able to run an algorithm and have it return either true or false that the object resides in this given photograph or not.  The actual feature "search" is what I'm shaky on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_Transform). It seems you have a fairly simple, fixed shape. The generalized Hough transform should be able to detect that shape at any rotation or scale in the image. You many need to threshold the original image, or pre-process it in some way for this method to be useful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local features to identify the object in image. [Feature detection wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29)

For example, you can calculate features on some referent image which contains only the object you're looking for and save the results, let's say, to a plain text file. After that you can search for the object just by comparing newly calculated features (on images with some complex scenes containing the object) with the referent ones.

Here's some good resource on local features:
[Local Invariant Feature Detectors: A Survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.4126&rep=rep1&type=pdf)